# How to extract a particular text from url in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a url like `http://www.somedotcom.com/all/~childrens-day/pr?sid=all`.

I want to extract childrens-day.  How to get that? Right now I am doing it like this

```
url = "http://www.somedotcom.com/all/~childrens-day/pr?sid=all"
url.match('~.+\/');
```

But what I am getting is `["~childrens-day/"]`.

Is there a (definitely there would be) short and sweet way to get the above text without `["~` and `/"]`   i.e   just `childrens-day`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a **negated** [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and a capture group `( )` and refer to capture group `#1`. The caret (`^`) inside of a character class `[ ]` is considered the negation operator.

```
var url    = "http://www.somedotcom.com/all/~childrens-day/pr?sid=all";
var result = url.match(/~([^~]+)\//);
console.log(result[1]); // "childrens-day"
```

See [`Working demo`](https://eval.in/89022)

**Note**: If you have many url's inside of a string you may want to add the `?` quantifier for a non greedy match.

```
var result = url.match(/~([^~]+?)\//);
```

Comment: What is this negated match?

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

```
var url = "http://www.somedotcom.com/all/~childrens-day/pr?sid=all"
var matches = url.match(/~(.+?)\//);
console.log(matches[1]);
```

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/xU4nZ6

Note that your regular expression wasn't actually properly delimited either, not sure how you got the result you did.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link http://regex101.com/r/xU4nZ6
I am new to this site seems like great place to go.

Comment: You are right the expression I got was different from what i had reported. Apologies I have corrected myself.

Comment: Still, this does what you want and that's all that matters :)

Comment: Yes Compadre, but in the interest of disclosure I reported this.

Answer (score 1):

Use non-capturing groups with a captured group then access the `[1]` element of the matches array:

```
(?:~)(.+)(?:/)
```

Keep in mind that you will need to escape your `/` if using it also as your RegEx delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.

```
url = "http://www.somedotcom.com/all/~childrens-day/pr?sid=all";
url.match('~(.+)\/')[1];
```

Just wrap what you need into parenteses group. No more modifications into your code is needed.

References: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: This wrapping around will give me a capturing group. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a string replace.

```
url.replace('~', '');
url.replace('/', '');
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp